# aws s3 sync include copying website redirect

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

[`aws s3 sync`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html) does not seem to copy the website redirect metadata by default.

There is this option:

> --website-redirect (string) If the bucket is configured as a website, redirects requests for this object to another object in the same
>   bucket or to an external URL. Amazon S3 stores the value of this
>   header in the object metadata.

But I'm looking for some kind of directive to get sync to copy the redirect of each file to the sync target. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

[aws s3 cp](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html) has the same option. I'm not sure how sync would do this since it is the **whole** directory, cp only does the single file unless you are using sync with specific files and not the whole dir.

It looks like the redirect is just metadata injected in the file and that is what the --website-redirect is setting.

> The following Amazon S3 API actions support the x-amz-website-redirect-location header in the request. Amazon S3 stores the header value in the object metadata as x-amz-website-redirect-location.
>   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/how-to-page-redirect.html
>
> [x-amz-website-redirect-location](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPOST.html)
>
> If the bucket is configured as a website, redirects requests for this object to another object in the same bucket or to an external URL. Amazon S3 stores the value of this header in the object metadata. For information about object metadata, see Object Key and Metadata.
>
> In the following example, the request header sets the redirect to an object (anotherPage.html) in the same bucket:
>
> x-amz-website-redirect-location: /anotherPage.html
>
> In the following example, the request header sets the object redirect to another website:
>
> x-amz-website-redirect-location: http://www.example.com/
>   For more information about website hosting in Amazon S3, see Hosting Websites on Amazon S3 and How to Configure Website Page Redirects in the Amazon Simple Storage Service Developer Guide.
>
> Type: String
>
> Default: None
>
> Constraints: The value must be prefixed by, "/", "http://" or "https://". The length of the value is limited to 2 K.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/how-to-page-redirect.html